# JRebel 6.4.6 plugin didn't work in IDEA 16 and Tomcat 9

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, intellij-idea, jrebel

I downloaded jrebel plugin in IDEA 16 and got a license. When I run my application with "jrebel run" button, I got the following output:

```
2016-07-07 13:40:18 JRebel:  
2016-07-07 13:40:18 JRebel:  #############################################################
2016-07-07 13:40:18 JRebel:  
2016-07-07 13:40:18 JRebel:  JRebel Agent 6.4.6 (201606221135)
2016-07-07 13:40:18 JRebel:  (c) Copyright ZeroTurnaround AS, Estonia, Tartu.
2016-07-07 13:40:18 JRebel:  
2016-07-07 13:40:18 JRebel:  Over the last 1 days JRebel prevented
2016-07-07 13:40:18 JRebel:  at least 0 redeploys/restarts saving you about 0 hours.
2016-07-07 13:40:18 JRebel:  
2016-07-07 13:40:18 JRebel:  License acquired from License Server: http://xxxxx.xxx.xxx
2016-07-07 13:40:18 JRebel:  
2016-07-07 13:40:18 JRebel:  Licensed to xxx.
2016-07-07 13:40:18 JRebel:  
2016-07-07 13:40:18 JRebel:  
2016-07-07 13:40:18 JRebel:  #############################################################
2016-07-07 13:40:18 JRebel:
```

and this

```
2016-07-07 13:40:20 JRebel: Directory 'E:\IdeaProjects\baobiao\target\classes' will be monitored for changes.
2016-07-07 13:40:20 JRebel: Directory 'E:\IdeaProjects\baobiao\src\main\webapp' will be monitored for changes.
```

but when I test modify a spring requestmapping annotation, it didn't work. The server output didn't show "JRebel: reloading class ..." word. So I opened the jrebel.log and there was an error in it:

```
2016-07-07 13:40:34.737 INFO  [13] [Licensing] Trying licenseServer licensing ..
2016-07-07 13:40:34.737 DEBUG [13] [Licensing] greedy: true, forStatusCheck: false
2016-07-07 13:40:34.737 DEBUG [13] [Licensing-LS] No offline lease found from local storage
2016-07-07 13:40:34.737 INFO  [13] [Licensing-LS] Contacting license server
2016-07-07 13:40:34.737 INFO  [13] [Licensing-LS] doAcquireLease to http://xxx.xxxxx.xxx ..
2016-07-07 13:40:34.809 DEBUG [13] [Licensing-LS] License server protocol 1.0+.
2016-07-07 13:40:34.809 INFO  [13] [Licensing-LS] License registered to xxx. License type: LS_MANAGED, LS version: 3.1.3, LS guid: null
2016-07-07 13:40:34.811 DEBUG [13] [Licensing-LS] License orderId , zero-ids: []
2016-07-07 13:40:34.813 INFO  [13] [Licensing-LS] Lease successfully acquired. Lease: com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.gv@2b2b7dd7[leaseId=1,offline=false,clientRandomness=dFyq4vacuNQ=,serverRandomness=H2ulzLlh7E0=,validFrom=Thu Jul 07 13:40:34 CST 2016,validUntil=Thu Jul 07 14:40:34 CST 2016]
2016-07-07 13:40:34.813 INFO  [13] [Licensing-LS] Trying to acquire the failover URL ..
2016-07-07 13:40:34.878 DEBUG [13] [Licensing-LS] License Server failover not configured.
2016-07-07 13:40:34.880 ERROR [13] [Licensing] Exception occurred while initializing license server licensing: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:705)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.gw.d(SourceFile:420)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.gw.a(SourceFile:92)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.iq.a(SourceFile:95)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.iq.a(SourceFile:57)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.in.a(SourceFile:79)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.SDKLicensingImpl.findAndValidateLicenseFromSource(SourceFile:543)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.SDKLicensingImpl.getLicenseInfo(SourceFile:73)
    at com.zeroturnaround.javarebel.or.getLicenceInfo(SourceFile:46)
    at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.reporting.MixpanelMetrics$3.build(SourceFile:133)
    at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.reporting.MixpanelMetrics$12.run(SourceFile:256)
    at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.reporting.MetricsExecutor.run(SourceFile:58)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have googled this question for a long time and still have no idea about it, is there anyone can help? Thanks very much!

Comment: Sounds like a bug in JRebel.  If you have a license you should be asking their tech support.

Answer (score 1):

Temporary workaround would be to take [offline lease](https://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/license-server/jrebel-configuration.html#offline-seats), but to troubleshoot why did the exception occur, send trace-level `jrebel.log` (add `-Drebel.log=trace` to server JVM arguments) to support@zeroturnaround.com along with link to this thread. See [manual](http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/misc/sendinglogs.html) if you have any questions about logs.